# Add rounding to ionic-alert with type: 'number'

Tags: ionic-framework

I have been struggling with this all day, I am creating an ionic-alert with the inputs as

```
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'test',
      type: 'number',
      min: '0.01',
      max: '10'
    },
  ],
```

The user experience I want is for it to display whole numbers except for the exception of 0.01 as the min, since 0 cannot be entered. So the flow would be 0.01 -> 1 -> 2 -> ... -> 10. Since the min is 0.01 the actual flow I am getting is 0.01 -> 1.01 -> 2.01 -> ... -> 9.01. I tried adding rounding in places but nothing worked, I also tried reading the documentation here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input. but I could not find anything that seemed like it would help.